# Conceptual questions about class, sub class and attributes in programming using python

Tags: python, class, attributes, subclass

In python, when I'm inheriting a class. what exactly am I inheriting? am I inheriting the class attributes? if yes, then does that mean I'm inheriting their default values too? and finally, do I necessarily have to set a default value or even mention the attributes in sub-class when I declare that I'm inheriting a class. Basically, what is the point of redeclaring the attributes in a subclass if there is any??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance):

> Execution of a derived class definition proceeds the same as for a base class. When the class object is constructed, the base class is remembered. **This is used for resolving attribute references: if a requested attribute is not found in the class, the search proceeds to look in the base class.** This rule is applied recursively if the base class itself is derived from some other class.

The following example should demonstrate that:

```
class A:
  foo = 0

class B(A):
  pass

# 'foo' isn't found in 'B' and the search proceeds in 'A'.
print(B.foo) # output: 0
```

If an attribute is defined in a subclass and in it's base, then a second attribute is created which is only defined in the subclass and takes precedence when being accessed. Example:

```
class A:
  foo = 1

class B(A):
  foo = 2

# 'A.foo' is a different object than 'B.foo'.
print(A.foo) # output: 1
print(B.foo) # output: 2
```